# How to print the total number of files in a sub-folder while iterating through a folder containing multiple subfolders?

Tags: python, logging

```
def duplicatechecker():
    logger.info("Duplicate Checker: START")
    logger.info("The process to check for duplicate files has been initiated.")

    for k in range(0,len(dirs)):
        DATA_DIR = Path(dirs[k])
        files = sorted(DATA_DIR.glob('*.xml'))
        logger.info (f"The number of files in the directory {dirs[k]} is {len(files)}".format(len(files)))
        invoice_number = {}
        duplicateFiles = []
        client_id = DATA_DIR.name
        
        for i in range(0,len(files)):
            tree = ET.parse(files[i])
            root = tree.getroot()
            record = root.findall('record')
            
            for j in range(0,len(record)):
                inv = record[j].find('invoice_number').text
                if inv in invoice_number:
                    xml = inv, files[i]
                    
                    duplicateFiles.append(xml)
                    duplicateFiles.append(invoice_number[inv])
                    print("Duplicate found and the invoice number is  " ,inv, "  and file name is  ", files[i],"other file is", invoice_number[inv])
                    copy_1 = os.path.basename(str(files[i]))
                    copy_2 = os.path.basename(str(invoice_number[inv]))
                    logger.info(client_id + " : " + "Duplicate" + " : " + str(inv) + " : "+ (copy_1[:-3]+"pdf") + " : " + (copy_2[:-3]+"pdf"))
                else:
                    invoice_number[inv] = files[i]
        logger.info("The number of duplicate files found is {}".format(len(duplicateFiles)/2))
        logger.info("Duplicate Checker: END for " + str(files[i])  )
        

duplicatechecker()
issuechecker()
logger.info("The process has been completed.")
logger.info("data_capture_issue uploaded")
```

This is the code I am working with.
I need to calculate the total number of files inside a folder.
this current code is not showing the result I want instead it print the file count of each folder separately and for some reason the second folder count is looping 4 time's

Comment: So you don't actually want _any_ log messages inside the function?

Comment: Return the value you want from the function, so you can use it?

Comment: It's unclear. See [ask]. 'call log from a defined variable'? What variable? Anyway, you want to defer calls on ```logger.info()```? For that, just store messages into a list inside the function, and call ```logger.info()``` for each messages outside the function.

Comment: It's still unclear. Are you dealing with subdirectories for each directory in ```dirs```? Do you want to count other files not matching to the pattern '*.xml'? See [mre]. Also if you want to notify me on your edit, you can add a comment calling me like '@relent95'.

Comment: @relent95 https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example was quite useful